# Advice on data-structure for represeting a Path in system

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures, stdvector, boost-graph

I have a system where i need to represent something similar as Path, a path just provides a route to reach a particular node. There can be multiple Path that can be used to reach same node.

I am currently representing a Path using vector of Nodes, I need to do operations like  replaceSubpath, containsNode, containsSubPath, appendNode, getRootNode, getLeafNode (very similar operations as done for string). All of these operations can be done on vector but performance for a large path can suck.

I am looking at using boost::graph but have no experience with it, I would like to know if using boost::graph would be correct/good data structure for these and similar operations?

Any advices on using some other data structure would be helpful too, I am aware I can optimize my vector solution by keep (multi) map of node to iterator etc.

Comment: `boost::graph` go with it.

Comment: Can you provide me some advice on how to do something like findSubPath, replaceSubPath using boost graph??

Comment: And the reason you don't want to represent it as a single string is?

Comment: Or, you know, `boost::path`?

Comment: @MooingDuck I have not heard of boost::path. Can link to it. The only path I find is boost::filesytem::path which I don't think would be a good fit here.

Comment: @pbible: Yeah, I forgot it was in `filesystem`.  I don't see why using a `boost::filesystem::path` would be worse in any way than a "vector of nodes", and it has all of these operations built in.  I don't know why you think it isn't a good fit here, this is it's exact use-case.

Comment: I guess it's pretty much the same as string but with delimiters. I don't see a find subpath or replace subpath. I don't think it is any better than string and it mixes semantics. Just my opinion though.

Comment: I see now, the question says 'Path in system'. [boost::Filesystem::Path](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html) would be a good option for that. I think the OP is concerned with Graphs though.

Comment: As I mentioned I can't use string (My system can have names of Node's represented as strings). The string are not unique but the Node's ptr/handle are hence I have to stick using to vector of Node*

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, the class `adjacency_list<>` from Boost.Graph *is* a vector of vertices. Vertex descriptor is an integer index in this vector.

Typically, a a tree or a path (path is a special case of a tree, right?) is represented as a predecessor map (like going backward from leaves to root or from target to source). In case of integer vertex descriptors, such predecessor map is simply `vector<int>`. I do not think you can represent a path or a tree in a more compact way.

Of course, such vector of predecessors can be substituted into string operations, esp. those from Boost.String_Algo, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/string_algo.html

Comment: Would you point me to some examples where these string algos were used on adjacency_list<> ??

Comment: For example, you start with some graph algorithm which generates predecessor map, e.g. Dijkstra shortest paths (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp) or Kruskal MST. 

Then you usually build a path of interest using this predecessor map. This path is essentially in the same form of predecessor map, but it has no unrelated vertices.

I assume you also have a potential subpath sp in the same form (as a predecessor map written as vector<int>)

Finally, you use boost::algorithm::find_first(sp, path) to answer questions like containsSubPath

Comment: So why should i need to use adjacency_list, can't i just keep vector<Node*> and apply various string operations on it using boost string algo library. The way I construct Path currently is just use vector.push_back(node).

Comment: I think @MichaelSimbirsky gives some good advice on an implementation. How will these paths/subpaths be consumed? When you "replaceSubPath" does that need to modify the original graph? Need to know more.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe it sounds like you are generating and editing paths in a graph, perhaps for optimizing routes etc.

I don't think that one data structure will give you what you want. I would keep the graph structure separate from the paths you are generating.

**replaceSubpath**: To me this would suggest a  [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) implementation. When you have the start and end of your path just paste it in and replace the subpath.

**containsNode**: Consider adding a map or set for fast containment checks.

**containsSubPath**: This could be tough depending on your other concerns and speed needs. If this is a very important operation consider a [Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) to test sub paths quickly. Keep in mind its better if the path doesn't change much since constructing them is O(N)

**appendNode**: Linked list will be easy here

**getRootNode**: Hold a pointer to the current root node.

**getLeafNode**: Hold a pointer to the current leaf node.

I would make a custom data structure that can address these concerns based on your goals. Finding subpaths and replacing them quickly might be competing performance goals. Usually more search optimization = more construction overhead making them less dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how some other code that you admire implements the need to manage paths.  For example, you might look at several implementation of Dijkstra and choose the one that looks best, most convenient or just to your taste.

IMHO it is not a good idea to model a "path" as an object, but rather think of it as a property of the nodes in a graph.

In general, I would consider 'marking' nodes that are on the path.  For example, the class you use to contain the properties of the nodes might have a flag indicating true if the node is on the path and an attribute with the index of the next node on the path.

Comment: I get what you are saying about marking paths. How will this address the OP's needs of finding and replacing subpaths? Also if many paths are needed adding flags to the vertex properties would not scale. Maybe I am missing something.